# How do you add abstract base class unique_ptrs to a map?

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm currently programming a game in C++. This game features a GameManager class. The GameManager class contains a map that holds pointers to game objects. I have defined a GameObject class that is an abstract class acting simply as an interface.

I have defined two classes that derive from the GameObject class: Enemy and Loot.

I want my GameManager class to contain a map of game objects, or rather, pointers to game objects. Because my GameManager owns these objects, I want the map to contain std::unique_ptr's.

However, I'm having a difficult time actually adding derived objects (e.g. Enemy and Loot) to this map.

I want my GameManager to iterate over the game objects and call the abstract methods. Essentially, my GameManager does not care whether or not something is an enemy, loot, or whatever, it just wants to be able to call the "draw" method as declared in the base class.

How would I go about adding a unique_ptr, that points to a derived class, to a map that contains unique_ptr's to the base class? My attempts so far lead to code I can't compile. I keep getting an error that states I am not allowed to dynamically cast a derived class pointer to a base class pointer.

I feel like this work fine if I was using raw pointers, but I'm intent on using smart pointers.

Code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>

class GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class  Enemy : GameObject
{
public:
    void draw() {};
};

class  Loot : GameObject
{
public:
    void draw() {};
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<GameObject>> my_map;

    // How do I add an Enemy or Loot object unique_ptr to this map?
    my_map[0] = dynamic_cast<GameObject>(std::unique_ptr<Enemy>().get()); // doesn't compile, complains about being unable to cast to abstract class

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show one of your attempts so far and the error message. The answer is probably surprisingly simple, but to make it understandable, it would help to know where you are coming from.

Comment: my_map.emplace(0, std::make_unique<Loot>());

Comment: @JaMiT I've updated it.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like a bit of a longer explanation than I was expecting is warranted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first cause of an error message is that a class type can never be used as the type for a `dynamic_cast`.  The target type of `dynamic_cast` must always be either a pointer to class type (meaning the result is null if the cast fails) or a reference to class type (meaning to throw an exception if the cast fails).

So improvement #1:

```
my_map[0] = dynamic_cast<GameObject*>(std::unique_ptr<Enemy>().get());
```

But this won't work because `GameObject` is a private base class of `Enemy`.  You probably meant to use public inheritance, but (when using `class` instead of `struct`) you must say so:

```
class Enemy : public GameObject
// ...
```

Next we'll find that the `=` within the map statement is invalid. The left side has type `std::unique_ptr<GameObject>`, which does not have any `operator=` that can take a `GameObject*` pointer.  But it does have a `reset` member for setting a raw pointer:

```
my_map[0].reset(dynamic_cast<GameObject*>(std::unique_ptr<Enemy>().get()));
```

Now the statement should compile - but it's still wrong.

Before getting to why it's wrong, we can make a simplification. `dynamic_cast` is needed for getting a pointer to derived class from a pointer to base class, or for many other type changes within a more complicated inheritance tree. But it's not needed at all to get a pointer to base class from a pointer to derived class: this is a valid implicit conversion, since every object with a derived class type must always contain a subobject of the base class type, and there's no "failure" case.  So the `dynamic_cast` here can just be dropped.

```
my_map[0].reset(std::unique_ptr<Enemy>().get());
```

The next problem is that `std::unique_ptr<Enemy>()` creates a null `unique_ptr`, and no `Enemy` object is created at all.  To create an actual `Enemy`, we can write instead either `std::unique_ptr<Enemy>(new Enemy)` or `std::make_unique<Enemy>()`.

```
my_map[0].reset(std::make_unique<Enemy>().get());
```

Still wrong, and in a slightly tricky way.  Now the problem is that the created `Enemy` object is owned by the temporary `std::unique_ptr<Enemy>` object returned by `make_unique`.  The `reset` tells the `std::unique_ptr<GameObject>` within the map that it should own a pointer to the same object.  But at the end of the statement, the temporary `std::unique_ptr<Enemy>` gets destroyed, and it destroys the `Enemy` object.  So the map is left with a pointer to a dead object, which is invalid to use - not what you wanted.

But the solution here is that we don't need to mess around with `get()` and `reset()` at all.  There is an `operator=` that allows assigning an rvalue `std::unique_ptr<Enemy>` to a `std::unique_ptr<GameObject>`, and it does the right thing here.  It makes use of the implicit conversion from `Enemy*` to `GameObject*`.

```
my_map[0] = std::make_unique<Enemy>();
```

(Note if you had a *named* `std::unique_ptr<Enemy>`, you would need to `std::move` it to allow the assignment, as in `my_map[0] = std::move(enemy_ptr);`. But `std::move` is not needed above because the result of `make_unique` is already an rvalue.)

Now this statement is much shorter and more legible, and will actually do what you want.

A comment also suggested the possibility

```
my_map.emplace(0, std::make_unique<Enemy>());
```

This is also valid, but there's a possibly important difference: if the map already has an object with key zero, the `=` version will destroy and replace the old one, but the `emplace` version will leave the map alone and the just-created `Enemy` will be destroyed instead.

Comment: I now understand why guys like Scott Meyers exist.

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` can only be used to convert between pointers, and references. `GameObject` is neither a pointer type, nor a reference type, so you cannot `dynamic_cast` to it.

You may have intended `dynamic_cast<GameObject*>` instead. however, you shouldn't `dynamic_cast` to a (pointer to) a base class. A pointer to derived type is implicitly convertible to the base class pointer. Use `static_cast` when implicit conversion is not desirable. Furthermore, that conversion is not possible either, since the cast is outside of any member function, and therefore cannot have access to the private base class.

Furthermore, you cannot assign a bare pointer to a unique pointer. To transfer ownership of a bare pointer to a unique pointer, you can use `unique_ptr::reset`. Howver, you should never store a pointer from `unique_ptr::get` into another  unique pointer. Doing so will result in undefined behaviour when both unique pointers destructors attempt to destroy the same object. Luckily in this case the pointer is value initialized, and therefore null, so the mistake has technically no consequences. But did you use null pointer intentionally? I suspect not.

Inserting a unique pointer to derived object into a map of unique pointers to base is simple. Let `ptr` be a unique pointer to `Enemy`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Enemy> ptr = get_unique_pointer_from_somewhere();
```

Simply move assign the unique pointer:

```
my_map[0] = std::move(ptr);
```

Or, you could use `emplace` member function of the map.

Finally, destructor `unique_ptr<GameObject>` will have undefined behaviour if it points to a derived object. To fix, declare the destructor of `GameObject` virtual.